# How to sort a container first by one property, than by another?

Tags: c++, sorting, containers, std, deque

With only one field is easy:

```
bool operator<(const MidiMsg &midiMsg) const {
    return (mPosition < midiMsg.mPosition);
}
```

But what if I need to order first by 1 member, than by another?

Tried this:

```
bool operator<(const MidiMsg &midiMsg) const {
    return (mPosition < midiMsg.mPosition && mId < midiMsg.mId);
}
```

But it seems that doesn't works.

Here's a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

struct MidiMsg {
    int mPosition;
    int mId;

    bool operator<(const MidiMsg &midiMsg) const {
        return (mPosition < midiMsg.mPosition && mId < midiMsg.mId);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(10);

    std::deque<MidiMsg> mNotes;

    MidiMsg note;

    note.mPosition = 0;
    note.mId = 1;
    mNotes.push_back(note);

    note.mPosition = 44100;
    note.mId = 1;
    mNotes.push_back(note);

    note.mPosition = 0;
    note.mId = 0;
    mNotes.push_back(note);

    note.mPosition = 44100;
    note.mId = 0;
    mNotes.push_back(note);

    note.mPosition = 0;
    note.mId = 2;
    mNotes.push_back(note);

    note.mPosition = 44100;
    note.mId = 2;
    mNotes.push_back(note);    

    std::sort(mNotes.begin(), mNotes.end());

    for (size_t index = 0; index < mNotes.size(); index++) {
        std::cout << mNotes[index].mPosition << " - " << mNotes[index].mId << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
0 - 1
0 - 0
44100 - 1
44100 - 0
0 - 2
44100 - 2
```

and not:

```
0 - 0
0 - 1   
0 - 2   
44100 - 0   
44100 - 1
44100 - 2
```

Comment: You'd need some extra checks: `(mPosition < midiMsg.mPosition || ( mPosition == midiMsg.mPosition && mId < midiMsg.mId));`.

Comment: @xEric_xD it seems correct. And if you have third? A chain of ||?

Comment: @markzzz That would work, but it'll quickly get messy, there's probably better solutions for a large number of properties.

Comment: @markzzz `std::tie` mentioned earlier does this but cleanly. Otherwise, you an apply Eric's solution more cleanly by chaining `if/else if`s instead of chaining `||`s.

Comment: Here's the result, not so fancy to use hehe `(mPosition < midiMsg.mPosition || ( mPosition == midiMsg.mPosition && mNoteNumber < midiMsg.mNoteNumber) || ( mPosition == midiMsg.mPosition && mNoteNumber == midiMsg.mNoteNumber && mId < midiMsg.mId));` :) Any other solution?

Comment: @markzzz `return std::tie(mPosition, mNoteNumber, mId) < std::tie(midiMsg.mPosition, midiMsg.mNoteNumber, midiMsg.mId);`

Comment: @aschepler it seems to works perfectly! Thanks! p.s. if you reply, you will get the accepted answer!

Comment: See the accepted answer at the duplicate for why it works.